# How to add 2 columns in my PowerShell HTML report?

Tags: powershell

I have PowerShell script, I wrote this code:

```
$computers  = Get-Content D:\Dev\Powershell\Powershell_TXT_FILE\pickup1.txt | Where {
    -not ($_.StartsWith('#'))
} | foreach {
    if (Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1) {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Server = $_
            Status = "Online"
        }
    } else {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $_
            Status = "Offline"
        }
    }
}
$computers | ConvertTo-Html -Property Server | Foreach {
    if ($_ -like "*<td>Online</td>*" ) {
        $_ -replace "<tr>","<tr bgcolor=green>"
    } else {
        $_ -replace "<tr>","<tr bgcolor=red>"
    }
} | Out-File D:\Share\Powershell\Powershell_TXT_FILE\test.html
```

How to add 2 or 4 columns on script.
I want to get this conclusion:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't add the columns **after** ConvertTo-Html. Do `$computers = $computers | Select-Object -Property *,Col3,Col4` before.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. its wor for me

Comment: word of caution.    -not ($_.StartsWith('#')) to filter out comment line may get confused if the command is not the first character of the line.

You might consider adding a trim to it..  like:

$computers  = Get-Content D:\Dev\Powershell\Powershell_TXT_FILE\pickup1.txt | Where {
    -not ($_.trim().StartsWith('#'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting columns 3 & 4 to exist but always be blank?

If so, try:

```
$computers  = Get-Content D:\Dev\Powershell\Powershell_TXT_FILE\pickup1.txt | Where {
    -not ($_.StartsWith('#'))
} | foreach {
    if (Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1) {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Server = $_
            Status = "Online"
        }
    } else {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Server = $_
            Status = "Offline"
        }
    }
}
$computers | ConvertTo-Html -Property Server | Foreach {
    if ($_ -like "*<td>Online</td>*" ) {
        $_ -replace "<tr>","<tr bgcolor=green>"
    } else {
        $_ -replace "<tr>","<tr bgcolor=red>"
} | %{$_ -replace "</td></tr>","</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"}
} | Out-File D:\Share\Powershell\Powershell_TXT_FILE\test.html
```

This adds the two columns with a space in them, to the end of each row in your table. (based on the  value in the HTML table.

Now, if you don't mind headers, it easier, add to the first line the data fields you want..

```
$computers  = Get-Content D:\Dev\Powershell\Powershell_TXT_FILE\pickup1.txt  | Where { -not ($_.StartsWith('#')) | select *,xx,yy
```

where XX and YY are your two added fields in your HTML table.